# A particle is projected from the ground at an angle theta with horizontal and some velocity

Tags: kinematics

For any position A, show that $\tan\alpha + \tan\beta =\tan\theta$[image]

MY SOLUTION:

We know that $\tan\theta=\frac{4h}{R}$

$$\tan\alpha=\frac{h}{x}$$
And 
$$\tan\beta = \frac{h}{R-x}$$
So $$\tan\alpha + \tan\beta = \frac{hR}{xR-x^2}$$
That’s as far as I could go up to. What should I do next?

Comment: You are confusing $h$ in the first formula (for $\theta$) where it has the meaning of maximum height, and in later formulas, where it has the meaning of the height at position $x$

Comment: You are right, but I still don’t know how to proceed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with the equations of motions along the two axis. In the horizontal axis you have $$x=ut\cos\theta$$
In the vertical direction you have $$h=ut\sin\theta-\frac12 gt^2$$
Taking $t=\frac{x}{u\cos\theta}$ from the first equation and plugging it into the second you get $$h=x\tan\theta-\frac12 g\frac{x^2}{u^2\cos^2\theta}$$
First, to calculate $R$ you set $h=0$. One solution is obviously $x=0$. For the other solution $$0=\tan\theta-\frac12 g\frac{R}{u^2\cos^2\theta}$$
This yields $$R=2\frac{u^2}{g}\tan\theta\cos^2\theta$$
Now rewrite the formula for the height in terms of $R$ as $$h=x\tan\theta-\frac{x^2}R\tan\theta$$
From here it should be easy, just plug this into your $\tan\alpha+\tan\beta$ equation:
$$\tan\alpha+\tan\beta=\frac{hR}{x(R-x)}=\frac{xR\tan\theta-x^2\tan\theta}{x(R-x)}=\tan\theta$$

Comment: Didn’t understand the part where you set h=0. Why did you substitute R for x^2

Comment: I substituted $R$ for $x$. At $x=R$ you get $h=0$. That's the definition of the range. Note that you have an $x$ in the left term and an $x^2$ in the right term. If $x\ne 0$, you can divide by $x$

Answer (score 2):

You may continue by substituting the following results for a projectile into your expression

$$ x = v_0t\cos \theta  $$
$$ R = \frac{v_0^2}{g}\sin2\theta $$
$$ h = v_0t\sin\theta - \frac{1}{2} g t^2 $$

and verify that

$$\frac{hR}{xR-x^2}= \tan\theta$$

---

The numerator is

$$hR = \left(x\tan\theta - \frac{gx^2}{2v_0^2\cos^2\theta}\right)\frac{v_0^2\sin 2\theta}{g}=x\tan\theta \left(\frac{v_0^2\sin 2\theta}{g}-x  \right)$$

and the denominator

$$x(R-x) = x\left(\frac{v_0^2\sin 2\theta}{g}-x  \right)$$

Their ratio comes out as

$$\frac{hR}{xR-x^2}= \tan\alpha + \tan\beta= \tan\theta$$

Comment: That doesn’t work. As Andrei, correctly pointed out, I can’t keep using h for all values, since it’s not maximum at x. So my working is wrong. I tried to do it again, but I am still stuck.

Comment: Please see the added lines in the answer